# Wordpress. Delete plugin automatic redirect to home page

Tags: wordpress

i am new in wordpress and install some plugins for my website. I did not install any theme yet, currently using default theme "Twenty Sixteen". Now i have to delete some plugins but unable to delete. When i am clicking on delete then its asking for delete all files and when i am clicking on it, its just redirect on my website home page and unable to delete that plugin. Same thing is happening for all plugins.

[image]

Comment: You deactivate that plugin and go to the plugins folder, wordpress/wp-content/plugins. There you will find that plugins folder, delete that folder. Then your plugin will get deleted from your site.

Comment: I know this way..but that problem happening every where.. even while changing the permalinks settings...